# how can get request parameter's value in multi ways in .htaccess url rewriting

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am beginner in PHP. I am using this rule in .htaccess to rewrite my product details page

```
RewriteRule ^product/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ product-details.php?id=$1&name=$2
```

When i am calling this URL

```
http://www.domain.com/product/1008/lorem-ipsum-is-dummy-text?ref=home_page&currency=GBP
```

page is loading successfully. On this page i can access id and name Request parameter's value but i can't access ref and currency parameter value.

How can i get these parameter's values? Is it possible or not with htaccess?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `QSA` flag to append query string.

Have your rule like this

```
RewriteRule ^product/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /product-details.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L,QSA]
```